# Where can I go and watch Flamenco shows in Istanbul?

Tags: culture, istanbul

Does Istanbul have cafés, bars or theatres where one can go and watch Flamenco shows?

I know there are places where they teach Flamenco but I just want to witness the performance.

Comment: ...you do realise flamenco is Spanish and not Turkish, yes?

Comment: Must-resist-the-temptation-to-create-the-[tag:flamenco]-tag-for-this-question.

Comment: Yeah very well aware . But its still popular in Turkey. So just hoping for a little luck.

Comment: You might want to contact the Istanbul Flamenco Association. They did not have events on their website since 2013: http://flamencoistanbul.com/ maybe they have still stuff going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck. There exists the [Istanbul Flamenco Association (website in Turkish only)](http://flamencoistanbul.com/) which can probably provide you with all the information you need. Below are their contact details:

```
Flamenko İstanbul Derneği
Firuzağa Mahallesi Bostanbaşı Caddesi Külünkoğlu Apartmanı no:5 /1
( Fransız Sokağı Alt Girişi )
Taksim
E-Posta: bilgi@flamencoistanbul.com
GSM : 0505 601 71 28 – 0535 233 47 70
```

They regularly organise festivals and events. For example, [the last Flamenco festival took place in February 2015](http://flamencoistanbul.com/2015/02/1-uluslararasi-flamenko-istanbul-festivali-acilis-konseri-21-subat-2015-cumartesi-saat-20-30-bkm/). [They also organised a workshop in the same month](http://flamencoistanbul.com/2015/02/1-uluslararasi-flamenko-istanbul-festivali-torombo-suarez-flamenko-dans-workshop-23-24-subat-2015/). It is therefore safe to assume that they are currently active. Indeed [their facebook page also shows recent activity](https://tr-tr.facebook.com/FlamencoTurkey). The website also has [a page dedicated to what they call Group Shows](http://flamencoistanbul.com/hakkimizda/soniquetes-gosteri-grubu/) which says you can contact the association for more information regarding

> Various events, exhibitions, openings, festivals, concerts, cocktails, dinners, exhibitions and special day of your lives